# Flexbox: set a border

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

this is my result of a further question: http://jsfiddle.net/20mx2406/
now I want these flexboxes to have a border, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">asdfo <br> asdf</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">test</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">test2</div>
</div>

.eqWrap { 
    display: flex; 
}

.eq { 
    padding: 10px;
    background: darkgrey;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
}

.equalHW { 
    flex: 1; 
}
```

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/20mx2406/13/
with

```
border: 1px solid Black;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `border-style:solid;`or check the other [border-style values](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp).